# How to build a black plot with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there any way to implement a black plot with jFreeChart?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what you mean by _black plot_.

Comment: Maybe like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36404170/230513) blue plot?